# How to get the details of a transaction in eway in curl?

Tags: php, curl

I have written a code in curl in php shown below :

```
<?php
      $username = "60CF3Ce97nRS1Z1Wp5m9kMmzHHEh8Rkuj31QCtVxjPWGYA9FymyqsK0Enm1P6mHJf0THbR";
      $password = "API-P4ss";
      $process = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/Transaction/44DD7aVwPYUPemGRf7pcWxyX2FJS-0Wk7xr9iE7Vatk_5vJimEbHveGSqX52B00QsBXqbLh9mGZxMHcjThQ_ITsCZ3JxKOY88WOVsFTLPrGtHRkK0E9ZDVh_Wz326QZlNlwx2");
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      $return = curl_exec($process);
      curl_close($process);
      var_dump($return);
?>
```

I am getting some error like shown below when the above code is used :

```
string(66) "HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST Content-Length: 0 Connection: Close "
```

I want to display all the details using this code ? Can anyone suggest how to do this ?

Comment: Nobody here !!!!!

Comment: You might find this easier using the [eWAY PHP SDK](https://www.eway.com.au/developers/sdk/php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$username = "60CF3Ce97nRS1Z1Wp5m9kMmzHHEh8Rkuj31QCtVxjPWGYA9FymyqsK0Enm1P6mHJf0THbR";
$password = "API-P4ss";
$process = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/Transaction/44DD7aVwPYUPemGRf7pcWxyX2FJS-0Wk7xr9iE7Vatk_5vJimEbHveGSqX52B00QsBXqbLh9mGZxMHcjThQ_ITsCZ3JxKOY88WOVsFTLPrGtHRkK0E9ZDVh_Wz326QZlNlwx2");
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$return = curl_exec($process);
curl_close($process);
var_dump($return);
```

Just some modification.. in curl option settings

Comment: I have made it like this but it is showing bool(false)

Comment: $accesscode = $_GET["AccessCode"];
   
      
   


$username = "60CF3C2oh7D+Q+/HOlIjFZdlmsgApfpvg8GXu+W8qr7bKM33cM3";
$password = "fvfgf";
$url = "https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/Transaction/".$accesscode;

$urlen = urlencode($url);
$process = curl_init($urlen);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$return = curl_exec($process);
curl_close($process);
var_dump($return);

Comment: make sure that user name and passwords  and access tokens are good (valid)

Comment: That must be provided by the api credentials when you make an account for the eway..

Answer (score 0):

The [eWAY PHP SDK](https://www.eway.com.au/developers/sdk/php) makes this, and any other actions, a lot easier:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

// eWAY Credentials
$apiKey = '60CF3C2oh7D+Q+/HOlIjFZdlmsgApfpvg8GXu+W8qr7bKM33cM3';
$apiPassword = 'fvfgf';
$apiEndpoint = 'sandbox';

// Create the eWAY Client
$client = \Eway\Rapid::createClient($apiKey, $apiPassword, $apiEndpoint);

// Query the transaction result.
$response = $client->queryTransaction($_GET["AccessCode"]);

$transactionResponse = $response->Transactions[0];

if ($transactionResponse->TransactionStatus) {
    echo 'Payment successful! ID: ' . $transactionResponse->TransactionID;
} else {
    $errors = split(', ', $transactionResponse->ResponseMessage);
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo "Payment failed: " . \Eway\Rapid::getMessage($error)."<br>";
    }
}
```

The full function doco [is here](https://eway.io/api-v3/?php#transaction-query)